# Link From Navbar/Menu to Pages in Views Folder Herokuapp with Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I made a website using Rails and I uploaded it on Heroku. I couldn't get the menu buttons from my index page/application.html.erb to link to the Store, About and Contact pages in the views folder.  They work in my pc/localhost:3000, though.

Here is a snippet from my navbar in the .html.erb file:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H1B6.jpg)

When I click on the menu items, I get this:
[screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWXzU.jpg)

Is it something that I need to do in Heroku?

I'm new at webdev. Please bear with me. :)

Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Read the help docs, learn how to ask a proper question, and show your code

Comment: Also post your `rake routes`. Try this also: put a / (forward slash) in front of the href in your erb files like, /store /about etc.

Comment: Thanks, @diego.greyrobot!  I took this advise and ran with it and came up with "/static_pages/store", "/static_pages/about" and "/static_pages/contact". And it worked!  Very much appreciated.  :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links on your page are relative, which means if you are on your root page (`/`) they link to `/store` `/about` and `/contact`.

But when you're on `/contact`, you'll go to `/contact/store` and `/contact/about`.

Try adding a slash (`/`) to the beginning of your href's

Comment: Thanks, @Koen.!  I took this advise and ran with it and came up with "/static_pages/store", "/static_pages/about" and "/static_pages/contact". And it worked!  Very much appreciated.  :D

Answer (score 0):

Instead of chasing down how to use an href tag in the .erb, could you go with something more along the 'rails way?' You get options like not reloading the page you are on:

in app/config/routes.rb

```
match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about', via: 'get'
```

in app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def about
  end
end
```

in app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb

```
<%= link_to_unless_current "About", about_path, class: "mycssclass" %>
```

Comment: Whoa.  Thanks!  This takes it even further.  I appreciate it, @Ted D